# /usr/bin/env: python3: No such file or directory when running script from cron

Tags: python, bash, cron

My BASH scrit has following line:

```
video_id=$(/usr/local/bin/yt-dlp --no-warnings --get-id "$ChannelPath")
```

it succeeds when runs from command line under certain user.

When it runs from cron, under the same user, it results in:

> /usr/bin/env: python3: No such file or directory

What could be different in these two cases?

- CentOS 7
- Python 3.11.0a4

Comment: Presumably *python3* isn't in the current PATH

Comment: Vlad, you were right. There are different PATH values in these two cases.

Answer (score 1):

There are some discussions whether you should use `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/python`. Proponents of the `env` variant say that it is better, because `env` uses the `PATH` to find the interpreter, and opponents say that the problem with the `env` variant is that it uses the `PATH`.

I dislike `env`, therefore I will give you a solution without it.

From the command line type

```
which python3
```

This will give you something like

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

In `/usr/local/bin/yt-dlp`, replace the first line with

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

(the output that you got from the `which` command.)

Or call `/usr/local/bin/yt-dlp` with explicitly the right interpreter:

```
video_id=$(/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp --no-warnings --get-id "$ChannelPath")
```

Comment: If I put `/usr/local/bin/python3` (the output of `which python3`) to the first lineof the script, instead of `/bin/bash`, it corrupts the script execution even in normal (not cron) mode. Secondly - all other bash scripts with yt-dlp calls are running fine in cron.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/yt-dlp`, not your bash script, sorry.

Comment: How? it is a compiled binary. And it is running fine from other scripts.

Comment: Hm. that is unexpected. What happens if you put `PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"` (the directory where your python3 lives) in the script before calling `yt-dlp`?

Comment: I moved the `python3` symlink from `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/bin` and it works now.

Comment: If you install the script properly (using `setuptools`, etc) a hashbang containing `python` will be set to whatever Python is used to install it, without have to *guess* where the end user has the correct Python installed.

Comment: How can you override what the shebang points to? I have a Cygwin environment where I don't have Python3 installed so scripts with the `/usr/bin/env python3` fails. But the python interpreter is in the path.

Comment: If you have a question on how to access Python in Cygwin, ask a new question. Don't try to "revive" an old question with a comment that has little to do with the original question.

Answer (score 1):

> it succeeds when runs from command line under certain user.
>
> When it runs from cron, under the same user, it results in:
>
> > /usr/bin/env: python3: No such file or directory
>
> What could be different in these two cases?

The difference is the environment in which the script runs.  In particular, the environment variables in it, and most particularly, the `PATH`.

When a user runs the script from the command line, it inherits the environment from which it was launched, which includes system-wide and possibly user-specific customizations that are engaged only for interactive shells.  (For example, the contents of the user's `~/.bash_profile` and / or `~/.bashrc` files.)  By default, when a shell is launched *non*interactively (by `cron`, for example) it does not read or execute any environment configuration.

Evidently,

1. Your `/usr/local/bin/yt-dlp` is or attempts to launch a Python script that has a shebang line using `/usr/bin/env` to choose and launch the `python3` binary.  That is, the affected script starts with

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   ```

   These days, that form is widely used and recommended in the Python world. The purpose is to use the `PATH` to locate the `python3` binary to use, as opposed to hard-coding that into the script.  However,
2. There is no *system* Python 3 installed on the machine.  (That is, none installed in the default path.)  The user who runs the script successfully is able to do so because they have an environment configured with some non-default directory in their `PATH` from which `python3` can be launched.

One possible solution would be to install CentOS's Python 3:

```
sudo yum install python3
```

If you need a different version of Python 3 (CentOS 7's is version 3.6) then you can instead set an appropriate `PATH` in the relevant `crontab` file, maybe something like

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
0 * * * * /path/to/my_script
```

Alternatively, you could modify your shell script to set the path there:

```bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
video_id=$(/usr/local/bin/yt-dlp --no-warnings --get-id "$ChannelPath")
```

or you could modify `/usr/local/bin/yt-dip` by altering its shebang (supposing that this is the affected Python script).

Comment: I moved the `python3` symlink from `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/bin` and it works now.

Comment: @Paul, I'm glad you have it working, but that particular solution is not one I would recommend.  You may run into issues if later you install a CentOS package that depends on CentOS's python3 package (resulting in that one replacing the one you put in `/usr/bin`).  If you can use CentOS's, then that's what you should do.  If not, you should use a mechanism, such as one of those I suggested, to tell the script where to find the right Python.

Comment: Last time I updated `yt-dlp` binary (it is not a script), it threw an error, that it won't work with Python 3.6 any more. That's why I had to remove 3.6 and started this complicated quest with installing Python 3.11. It is unlikely that I will be forced to install Python 3.6 again. Hopefully 3.11 is backwards compatible with 3.6.

Comment: cron seems to ignore crontab. there is `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` defined in `/etc/crontab`, but the real PATH is outputted like `/usr/bin:/bin`. The real crontab seems to be in `/var/spool/cron/$USERNAME`

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `python3` symlink from `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/bin` and it works now.

`/usr/local/bin` was the suggested location in internet-manuals about how to compile and install Python 3.11 in CentOS7.

A better solution is to add

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

to the first line of crontab. Although it should be not `/etc/crontab`, but

```
crontab -l > crontab.txt
```

then edit crontab.txt

then

```
crontab crontab.txt
```

Comment: You should absolutey leave `/usr/bin` alone; this location is reserved for system binaries supplied by your OS on modern Linux distros. The simple and straightforward solution is to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `PATH`.